# How can I add an IPreferenceChangeListener that responds to any preference change?

Tags: eclipse, preferences

I'd like to add a listener that will fire when ***any*** Eclipse preference is changed.

I know how to do this for a specific preference page using the Activator of the UI plugin that declares the page. You might use the following API called from the Activator.start() method:

```java
getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(IPropertyChangeListener listener)
```

But I'd like the listener to be notified whenever any preference is changed. I tried the following, called from my Activator.start() method:

```java
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
...
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
        addMyPreferenceChangeListener();
    }

    private IPreferenceChangeListener fPreferenceChangeListener;
    private void addMyPreferenceChangeListener() {
        fPreferenceChangeListener = new IPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void preferenceChange(PreferenceChangeEvent event) {
                System.err.println("PreferenceChangeEvent");
            }
        };
        IEclipsePreferences prefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("/");
        prefs.addPreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener);
    }
}
```

I hoped the "/" of getNode might indicate the root of the preference, but this doesn't seem to work; the println() is not executed when I make a change to the preferences (eg: Window > Preferences > General > Always run in background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have a single listener that is notified for all nodes,  you have to add a listener to each node you are interested in.

You can find all the existing nodes using an `IPreferenceNodeVisitor`

```java
IPreferencesService prefsService = Platform.getPreferencesService();

IEclipsePreferences root = prefsService.getRootNode();

root.accept(visitor);
```

You will also have to use `IEclipsePreferences.addNodeChangeListener` to be told about new nodes.

Also note that the `start` method of your activator does not run until some other code in your plugin is used - it does not normally run during Eclipse startup.

Comment: Hi greg-449, excellent thanks for that. I can get the first bit to work - the visitor - but I'm not sure how to complete the addNodeChangeListener. In the removed(NodeChangeEvent event) or added(NodeChangeEvent event) methods I can do event.getChild() but it gives me org.osgi.service.prefs.Preferences. What can I do with that? I was expecting a IEclipsePreferences node so I can execute another accept(visitor) and add my listener to the new node.

Comment: IEclipsePreferences extends Preferences, I think you should be able to just cast to value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Inside added(NodeChangeEvent event) I was able to do this:        IEclipsePreferences node = (IEclipsePreferences) event.getChild();
       node.addPreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener); However I couldn't remove the listener in removed() because an exception is thrown because the node has been removed. I've seen other code mention this.

Comment: I'd like to post the complete answer as source. What is the best way to do that on SO? Should I edit the original code in my original question (doesn't seem like the best option because you lose some context) or use the "Answer your question" button?

Comment: If it is an answer post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to greg-449 for his answer. Here's my final code for reference.
The preference listeners are added from the Activator start method. Note this plugin is started at launch using the `extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup"`.
Listeners are removed when the plugin stops.

Any changes to Preferences cause "PreferenceChangeEvent" to be printed. I hook into this point to do the actual work I want; not shown.
If a new preference node is created (for instance creating a new environment variable (Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Environment) and pressing Apply) then "PreferenceChangeEvent" is printed. Also printed whenever the value of the variable is changed subsequently in Preferences.

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IPreferenceNodeVisitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IPreferencesService;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences.INodeChangeListener;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences.IPreferenceChangeListener;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences.NodeChangeEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences.PreferenceChangeEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.service.prefs.BackingStoreException;

public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
```

...

```
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
        addPreferenceChangeListeners();
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        removePreferenceChangeListeners();
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

    private IPreferenceChangeListener fPreferenceChangeListener;
    private void addPreferenceChangeListeners() {
        /*
         * Create a single preference change listener; the same listener is
         * used for all the Preference Nodes.
         */
        fPreferenceChangeListener = new IPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void preferenceChange(PreferenceChangeEvent event) {
                System.err.println("PreferenceChangeEvent");
            }
        };

        IPreferencesService prefsService = Platform.getPreferencesService();
        IEclipsePreferences root = prefsService.getRootNode();
        /*
         * Create a visitor for adding the pref change listener to each node.
         */
        IPreferenceNodeVisitor addingVisitor = new IPreferenceNodeVisitor() {
            public boolean visit(IEclipsePreferences node) throws BackingStoreException {
                if(null!=fPreferenceChangeListener) {
                    System.out.println("Adding pref change listener");
                    node.addPreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener);
                    /*
                     * Add a addNodeChangeListener so that if any new preference nodes
                     * are added they will also have our listener added too. 
                     */
                    node.addNodeChangeListener(new INodeChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void removed(NodeChangeEvent event) {
                            System.out.println("removed: event=" + event.toString());
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void added(NodeChangeEvent event) {
                            System.out.println("added: event=" + event.toString());
                            IEclipsePreferences node = (IEclipsePreferences) event.getChild();
                            node.addPreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        /*
         * Add the listener to the root and all its children
         */
        try {
            root.accept(addingVisitor);
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class PreferenceChangeRemovingVisitor implements IPreferenceNodeVisitor {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(IEclipsePreferences node) {
            if(null!=fPreferenceChangeListener) {
                System.out.println("Removing pref change listener");
                node.removePreferenceChangeListener(fPreferenceChangeListener);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void removePreferenceChangeListeners() {
        IPreferencesService prefsService = Platform.getPreferencesService();
        IEclipsePreferences root = prefsService.getRootNode();
        IPreferenceNodeVisitor removingVisitor = new PreferenceChangeRemovingVisitor(); 
        try {
            root.accept(removingVisitor);
        } catch (BackingStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fPreferenceChangeListener = null;
    }
}
```